# how to group collection of datoms (tuples) and get total sum of it's attribute values?

Tags: clojure, datomic

Basically I want to get map which contains transactions (list of maps) grouped into a collection for Trading, Paper, Backtest keys.

I'm not sure how to go about doing this so I took a wild guess below.

What I'm trying to do is get the balances of each transaction (entity) for each group (either trading, paper, backtest).

```
(def results types-of-accounts)

(def trading-tx-collection (results :trading))
(def backtest-tx-collection (results :backtest))
(def paper-tx-collection (results :paper))

(def trading-total-balance (get-total-balance trading-tx-collection))
(def backtest-total-balance (get-total-balance backtest-tx-collection))
(def paper-total-balance (get-total-balance paper-tx-collection))

(def grand-total (+ trading-total-balance backtest-total-balance paper-total-balance))


(defn get-total-balance
  "calculates total balance of all transactions"
  [account-type-collection]
  (reduce + (map :balance :account/balance account-type-collection)))

;; should return {:trading [[entity map] [entity map] [entity map]]
;;                :paper [[entity map] [entity map] [entity map]]
;;                :backtest [[entity map] [entity map] [entity map]]}
;; where a [entity map] looks like [:accounting/type "Trading :accounting/balance 300]
(defn types-of-accounts
  "Get a map of entities grouped into one of 3 account types: TRADING PAPER BACKTEST"
  [user]
  (initialize-db)
  (let
    [conn (d/connect uri)]
    (pull db '[:trading (:account/trading) :paper (:account/paper) :backtest (:accounting/backtest)]
      (q '[:find ?e
           :in $ ?user
           :where
           [?e :account/user ?user]]
         (d/db conn)
         user))))
```

Answer (score 1):

I made up some sample data and made some assumptions about it, so I hope this is still useful as an example. If you include a sample input it

```
accounting> (def transcations [[:accounting/type "Trading :accounting/balance 300"]
                               [:accounting/type "Trading :accounting/balance 300"]
                               [:accounting/type "Paper :accounting/balance 300"]
                               [:accounting/type "Paper :accounting/balance 100"]
                               [:accounting/type "Paper :accounting/balance 300"]
                               [:accounting/type "Backtest :accounting/balance 300"]])
#'accounting/transcations
accounting> (->> transcations
                 (map second)
                 (map #(clojure.string/split % #" "))
                 (map #(hash-map (keyword (first %)) (Integer. (nth % 2))))
                 (apply merge-with +))
```

the interesting part is the call to merge-with on the last line.

Comment: what is that `->>` called and how does it differ from `->`? I know that's threading and it's another way of writing long nested lists. but where does the values flow if everything is immutable? or does that generate a whole new data. and why the # in front of the `(` ?

Comment: ->> is pronounced "thread last" and it just fills in the last position with the previous expression. -> "thread first" puts the previous expression as the first argument. ->> makes it the last argument. #(function-to-call % %2 %3) is just a shorthand for (fn [arg1 arg2 arg3 ] (function-to-call arg1 arg2 arg3).

Comment: i guess you've overcomplicated it (due to the misunderstanring of a data structure) as far as i can infer, every record should be of the form `[:accounting/type "Trading" :accounting/balance 300]`

Comment: @leetwinski is correct I noticed that just now. well I'm thinking the simpler way is just doing a `filter?` via `:accounting/type "Trading"` and then doing a reduce to get the total balance. But I am bit wary of doing this because it isn't a one single move to do it all at once (which seems to be the solution I'm seeking). So I'd have to filter through the vector of transactions 3x and do reduce 3x which hardly seems efficient. So what I was originally trying to do is go through the vector of transactions ONCE and stick it in the appropriate key in the output map, and doing a map/reduce.

Comment: You can do it with one call to merge  Make a function that takes the existing result and the new map and sums it into the correct key.

Comment: @ArthurUlfeldt I think that might do it. discovered this `(merge-with + 
            {:a 1  :b 2}
            {:a 9  :b 98 :c 0})   ` but not sure how to make it 'ignore' other attributes in each transaction. in this case :c because it has random strings which shouldn't be conjoined.